# Cannot add a project to a Tomcat server in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jst

I cannot add my project to a server in Eclipse - why is that?

I installed all necessary tools (Web Dev, Java EE, Server Adapters, and Tomcat itself, everything)

I configured the runtime environments, adjusted all Java Versions to JDK 6 (because it should run on Tomcat 6), but still the left side of the dialogue where I could add resources is empty when creating a new server.

What else could I try?

PS: I am using [Eclipse v4.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Juno) on Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: **Right Click on App-->Run on Server**, and here try to add your project to the server. Try this once.

Comment: That is not available in the menu of "Run As", I only have "Java Applet", "Java Application" and "JUnit Test"

Comment: Did you download Eclipse EE or Eclipse?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You didn't create your project as "Dynamic Web Project", so Eclipse doesn't recognize it like a web project. Create a new "Dynamic Web Project" or go to *Properties* → *Projects Facets* and check *Dynamic Web Module*.

Comment: Is there a way to just change the project? If not, how would I import the contents after creating a new, empty project?

Comment: or go to Properties -> Projects Facets and check Dynamic Web Module.

Comment: In project Properties, you will see "Project Facet" section. In it check "Dynamic Web Module" (appropriate version), and additional technologies you are using (JSF or JSP...).

Comment: I also checked `Java` along with `Dynamic Web Module` and it works fine!!

Answer (score 32):

1. Right click on the project name in the *Package Explorer* view.
2. Select *Properties*
3. Select *Project Facets*
4. Click on the *Runtimes* tab
5. Check *Server*
6. Click on <kbd>OK</kbd>

And now:

1. Right click on the server name in the *Servers* view
2. Click on *Add and Remove...*
3. Move resources to the right column

Comment: Created my project as a Dynamic Web project, everything had the right check boxes, but had to back the version of the Dynamic Web off from 6.0 to 5.0 for use with Tomcat v10.1.5 (in Project Facets panel).  Then I could add/remove my project.

Answer (score 7):

If you are able to see the project in Eclipse project explorer but unable to see the project while adding the project to the web server, follow project properties -> Project Facets, make sure ***Dynamic Web Module*** & ***Java*** were ticked.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue as adding *Dynamic Web Module* to *Project Facets*

1. right click on project name in the *Package Explorer* view.
2. select *Properties*
3. Select *Project Facets*
4. Activate *Dynamic Web Module*
5. Click on <kbd>OK</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

1. Right-click on project
2. Go to properties => project factes
3. Click on runtime tab
4. Check the box of the server
5. Then ok

Close the eclipse and start the server you will able to see and run the project.

Comment: Please don't deface your answer by rolling back our improvements.

Answer (score 4):

Go to project properties -> **Project Facets. Make sure the Dynamic Web Module and Java is checked.**

Apart from it, **"Cloud Foundry Standalone Application" needs to be un-checked**, if it is already selected. By default, few IDEs preselect this option.

Answer (score 3):

After following the steps suggested by previous posters, do the following steps:

- Right click on the project
- Click *Maven*, then *Update Project*
- Tick the checkbox "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases", then click OK

You should be good to go now.

Answer (score 2):

In my case:

Project properties → *Project Facets*. Make sure "Dynamic Web Module" is checked. Finally, I enter the version number "2.3" instead of "3.0". After that, the Apache Tomcat 5.5 runtime is listed in the *"Runtimes"* tab.

Comment: I had to remove version 4.0, and put version 3.0.  After that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Steps I used to resolve it:

1. Double click on Tomcat Server in the Servers tab.
2. In a dropdown next to Runtime Environment:, select Apache Tomcat `your version`
3. Click on save.

Now, you should be able to add to server on right click *"Add and Remove"*.

Note: Additionally, when on clear/run, you get an error for multiple instances, open server.xml and ensure that it contains a single instance of each application and not multiple.

Comment: Hi Mahesh, can you please format the answer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the .project file was read-only (it was pulled from the source code control system that way). Making it writable resolved the issue.

[Eclipse v4.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Oxygen).

Answer (score -1):

For me:

It was [Eclipse v4.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Mars) which did not support [Java SE 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7), so I added [Java SE 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8). It worked.

Comment: I've been running Mars 4.5.1 for months with jdk7.