# Spring boot how to make project run on server in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot

> I am new to Spring Boot, I have sample spring boot code in my Eclipse
>   IDE.
>
> Now to run the project. In project there is class "Application", I run
>   that using Run As Java Application and then Its running on given port.
>
> But I want it to run using Run on Server option of Eclipse, so
>   whenever I try to run that on server it gives me 404.

Please give me any idea to resolve this issue.

Code:

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(Application.class);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(beanNames));
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.address=localhost
server.port=8080
server.contextPath=/spring-security-cas
app.service.security=http://localhost:8080/j_spring_cas_security_check
app.service.home=http://localhost:8080/
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.esco.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo-spring-security-cas</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Usefull for accessing to jsp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END Usefull for accessing to jsp -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>org.esco.demo.ssc.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Note: Project running when run Application as Run as Java Application,
problem is I want it to run using Run on Server option.

Comment: Please share your pom.xml,main class & application.properties

Comment: Deploy as a war instead of runnable jar. Also make use of "@SpringBootApplication" in main class then remove the following property "app.service.security" it should work.

Comment: maybe you mean how to add a project to a server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380125/cannot-add-a-project-to-a-tomcat-server-in-eclipse

Answer (score 9):

If you want to deploy it to a container, instead of using the embedded container follow [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) in the reference guide.

In short the steps are

1. Use `war` packaging instead of `jar` packaging
2. Let your `Application` class extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` and implement the `configure` method.
3. Mark the container dependencies (tomcat I guess) as `provided`

So in a nutshell

1. Change `<packaging>jar</packaging>` to `<packaging>war</packaging>`
2. Change your `Application`

   ```
   public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
       ...
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
           return builder.sources(Application.class);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add tomcat dependency as `provided`.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifcatId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

For more elaborate information check [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

Comment: I have followed above steps.

Comment: And? Make sure eclipse is getting all dependencies, also check your logs. When changing packaging, you might need to reimport the project. Also make sure you have a servlet container that actually supports servlet 3.0.

Comment: I delete project from eclipse and then import it , clicking on Run on Server I got error in my console. as below : 
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration'

Comment: Don't add code as comments... Update your question with it. When updating also add your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a tomcat instance on eclipse? What are the logs saying? That there is no application deployed?

Then you need to deploy a war to tomcat -

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Change -

```
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

To

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

And it should work.

Comment: change the jar to war but the problems continues,
 I mean tomcat instance on eclipse, 
I am not getting any logs

Comment: Isnt there a console output window on eclipse? Check Window > Show View>

Comment: Actully I am getting the server startup message in console " Server startup in 412 ms"

Comment: Post the whole output to your question?

Comment: Have you actually read the documentation on that link? It also explains the use of `SpringBootServletInitializer`. Which you MUST use if you want a deployable artificat.

Comment: @M.Deinum We havent confirmed the problem yet

Comment: @M.Deinum I changed my Application class and extend it by SpringBootServletInitializer. But still I have not got success.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do I need to include web.xml? I mean without adding it I will not able to run it on server? Please correct me.

Comment: Only extending it isn't going to do much, you still ahve to override a method and put something meaningful in there.

Comment: @farrellmr His `Application` class isn't extending it, without that extends it will never run on a server. Unless you are on a very old server, use Spring Boot Legacy and provide a web.xml...