# Run spring boot application on server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

Im new to spring application development.

How can i run my application while developing stage at tomcat server.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994693/spring-boot-how-to-make-project-run-on-server-in-eclipse) i can see that the solution for final deployment. i just need to change some on ui every time i need to stop and start again. it kills me. So can you please help me her ??

my pom.xml dependencies are

org.springframework
        spring-binding
        1.0.6

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I don't understand. You run it like you would run any other executable on a server.

Comment: If you want to refresh the static content of your applications, maybe this post could help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221922/spring-boot-update-frontend-without-restarting-the-application

Comment: Where you need to start and stop frequently ? eclipse or server ?

Comment: add devtools dependency to your project. it autodeploys the project when you made changes.

Comment: <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati  i want to run again and again the application. not the eclipse. i dont want this happend

Comment: With eclipse try devtools and set build project automatically flag.

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati it is enabled . While i change some thing on my HTML or some changes on java. I need to run the application. Again. Im asking that is there is any way to avoid running the application every time that i made changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add devtools dependency to your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Whenever files change in the classpath, applications using spring-boot-devtools will cause the application to restart. The benefit of this feature is the time required to verify the changes made is considerably reduced.

Comment: The managed version is 2.1.1.RELEASE The artifact is managed in org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.1.RELEASE this is the error that i am getting now

Comment: Have you added spring-boot-starter-parent dependency to your project?
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent> To get rid of this error you have add starter parent dependency.

Comment: If you are using any third party dependency i.e. hibernate or camel, A safer way to use is to override Boot's dependency management. As you are using spring-boot-starter-parent as your pom's parent you can do that by overriding the version property.

Answer (score 1):

Create the application with maven install gol, generating a jar, run the jar on your server with> java -jar your_jar.jar

Comment: I can't create jar every time that i am started the development .