# Couldn't load the Tomcat Sever Configuration at C:Program Files/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/conf

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I've apache-tomcat-8.5.61 in my Program files. And when I try to refer it using eclipse, I'm getting the following error. I'm not able to understand the reason it's showing this error. 
[image]

Did I miss something here?

Comment: did you try it by the preferences tab?

Comment: @OmarAmaoun Yes. I'm able to add through preferences tab. Yet, when I try to link the tomcat from Servers tab, I'm getting this issue.

Comment: did you see this answer please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380125/cannot-add-a-project-to-a-tomcat-server-in-eclipse

Comment: @OmarAmaoun didn't help me.